# If $X$ is a normed space and $X=Y\oplus{Z}$, is $X$ homeomorphic to $Y\times Z$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\left\|{\cdot}\right\|)$ be a real normed space with $X=Y\oplus{Z}$, where $Y,Z$ are normed subspaces of $X$. We give $Y\times Z$ the norm $\left\|{(y,z)}\right\|=\left\|{y}\right\|+\left\|{z}\right\|$.

> Isn't it always true that $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times Z$?

I would think that the natural homeomorphism would be $f(x)=(y_x,z_x)$ where $x=y_x+z_x$ and $y_x\in Y,z_x\in Z$. This is a linear function (and bijective) so if $X$ is finite dimensional then $f$ is a homeomorphism. But what about infinite dimensional spaces?

In order to prove the continuity we would need to find $K>0$ such that $\left\|{y}\right\|+\left\|{z}\right\|\le K\left\|{y+z}\right\|$. Is this possible?

Edit: Note that I'm looking for a homeomorphism not a linear isomorphism, so maybe we don't actually need the function $f$.

Comment: By homeomorphic, do you mean linearly homeomorphic or just homeomorphic as topological spaces?

Comment: Just homeomorphic as topological spaces.

Comment: Your $f$ needn't be continuous: Let $\phi:X\to\mathbb K$ be a discontinuous linear functional, $Y$ the kernel of $\phi$, and $Z$ the span of some $z$ with $\phi(z)=1$. Then the "projections" onto $Y$ and $Z$ are given by $y(x)=x-\phi(x)z$ and $z(x)=\phi(x)z$.